# Can I "cryptsetup ... luksFormat" a partition formatted with Ext4, or must it be unformatted?

Tags: luks, cryptsetup

I would like to setup Full Disk Encryption (FDE) for an external harddrive. My question is about the sequence of formatting. Will the following sequence work fine or do I need to run luksFormat on an **unformatted** partition?

1. use gparted to create an msdos partition-table
2. use gparted to create and format a partition with Ext4 (let's say partition name is "sdb1")
3. unmount partition /dev/sdb1
4. open Terminal and run command `sudo cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/sdb1`

Do I now have an FDE external harddrive? I've read in a few places that the luksFormat command is run on an unformatted partition. Is this a requirement? Have I done anything wrong by formatting with Ext4 and then running luksFormat? Any guidance on how to properly achieve FDE for external harddrive would be great. Thanks.

performing this task on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Your steps are out of order. Make a partition, crytpsetup, then open the crypt and format. See http://www.cyberciti.biz/hardware/howto-linux-hard-disk-encryption-with-luks-cryptsetup-command/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the order wrong. Assuming sdb1 ...

```
sudo dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sdb1
sudo cryptsetup -y -v luksFormat /dev/sdb1
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb1 $name #change "$name" to any name you wish
# now format
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/$name
sudo mkdir /media/mount_point
sudo mount /dev/mapper/$name /media/mount_point
```

See:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/hardware/howto-linux-hard-disk-encryption-with-luks-cryptsetup-command/

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedFilesystemHowto3

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt

Comment: if I create 1)partition 2)Ext4-format 3)luksFormat, it appears to work. Do you know the reasoning/purpose behind 1)partition 2)luksFormat 3)Ext4-format? Does Ext4-format before luksFormat create a vulnerability or something?

Comment: post the commands you ran. As a part of setting up a crypt you write random data to the disk (partition) which will destroy the data. If you did not write random data to the disk. See http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/10407/why-do-some-luks-tutorials-mention-overwriting-the-partition-with-random-data

Comment: the commands I ran are summed up in my orig question (1-4): only CLI use was for luksFormat part (step 4). Brand new drive (no prev use), do you still recommend random write? I will seek more learning to understand why Ext4 format must occur after luksFormat. Thanks bodhi for detailing steps and the links.

Comment: @user308393 Just because something appears to work, it does not mean that it actually works. If you ext4 format then luks format you will get a partition with ext4 data structures and a luks header. The problem is that usage is mutually exclusive - using one and then the other will result in data corruption.

Comment: is random write necessary on brand new drive or only needed for previously used drive?

Comment: See the link I gave you from security.stackexchange

Comment: bodhi, could you answer one more thing: some of the links instruct wiping the /dev/<partition-name> and then running luksFormat (your example does it this way). Other links instruct running luksFormat and then wiping the /dev/mapper/<name>. Do both sequences give same result? Do I need to be concerned with which sequence I use?

Comment: First you write random data to /dev/sdb1 for reasons I gave you in the link. Next you make the crypt (cryptsetup). then you decrypt the data (luksOpen ...) . the decrypted data is at /dev/mapper/$name . Of course there is no initial data. You can then choose to write zeros to the decrypted data (/dev/mapper/$name) or not, does not really matter IMO. Note this is NOT the same as writing zeros to /deb/sdb1 . When you un mount /dev/mapper/$name, and close the crypt, your data is encrypted and can not be accessed without again running luksopen and mounting.

Comment: I think your problem is you do not understand the structure. Think of this as containers within containers like Russian dolls. (Physical device -> partition -> crypt -> file system -> data ) See also https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeEncryptedPartitions I think your confusion comes from not understanding what part you are writing data to (raw partition, crypt, filesystem).